# Codeigniter and angular js integration

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am new into both and unable to access angular in my codeigniter code. I have created simple code in angular which is :

```
<body ng-app="">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</body>
```

I have also inserted both angular.min.js and angular-route.min.js inside  tag but when I run this application, it displays following error in console :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

While if I execute this code seperately, it works perfect. Can anyone please help me out in resolving this issue. 
PS : I know many have asked this question earlier. I tried given solution but nothing worked out in my case. May be I am unable to understand the solution they have provided.
It will be a great help if someone provides a simple solution of given problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your angularjs code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: If it helps, I'm fairly certain this isn't a CodeIgniter problem in any way. You can treat the view like any old HTML file, there's no magic.

Comment: @Goose then why I am facing this error?

Comment: You are facing this error coz you have failed to add a module in your angular code. Can u show us your angular code (JS part)

Comment: @NehaMangla you'd have the error outside of CodeIgniter as well. Go ahead and create an HTML file and get it working there. if it works there, just paste it in a CodeIgniter view. Angular is client side, not server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Will help you

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Akshay. It worked for me. So the error was because I was not including jquery library?